# DB Error: constraint violation

Tags: upgrade, backups

Help! I just upgraded Civi from 4.7.3 to 4.7.7, but my host timed out during the DB upgrade and it was unable to complete. So I restored a backup of the database and was going to try again, but now every time I do anything with Civi, it gives me a DB Error: constraint violation.

I can't access any of Civi's backend now; it all gives me the same error. And when I try to run the upgrade script, it gives me the error after I click upgrade.

Is there anything I can do? Is my entire Database and my backup worthless now??

Comment: Begin by looking at the CiviCRM log files (https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers#Debuggingfordevelopers-Logfiles). That should provide a clue regarding the nature of the constraint violation. It may be something you can fix manually and then proceed with the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, we had an issue on 4.6.24 just now.

The CiviCRM log file stated: -

```
DB Error: constraint violation
```

The debug information should give you the MySQL table name. For some reason, a custom table (civicrm_value_tablename_id) was linked by foreign key (entity_id) to the wrong table. In my case, it was the civicrm_event table, whereas it should have been to the civicrm_participant table.

My solution was to truncate (empty) the civicrm_value_tablename_id table, remove the incorrect foreign key, then add the correct foreign key.

Strange though that I had to do this manually as the CiviCRM custom data set screen showed that the Custom Data set in question is 'Used for' (or extends Participants).